# Error PayPal plugin on grails 2.0.0.RC3

Tags: grails

I use grails 2.0.0.rc3, when I install PayPal plugin I have this error:

```
Error Compilation error: startup failed:
/Users/sartre/.grails/2.0.0.M1/projects/testapp/plugins/paypal-0.6.4/grails-app/controllers/org/grails/paypal/PaypalController.groovy: -1: The return type of java.lang.Object notify() in org.grails.paypal.PaypalController is incompatible with void notify() in java.lang.Object
. At [-1:-1] @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
```

How can I fix it?

Many thanks for any idea

Comment: That awkward moment when you ran into the same error, and not single answer was in sight. :(

Answer (score 1):

Incompatibility change in grails 2.0!!
It seems that it is related to a small change in grails 2.0.

> It is now possible to define controller actions as methods instead of using closures as in previous versions of Grails. (from official doc : http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/introduction.html#webFeatures)

It behaves like the closure notify in PaypalController overrides the Object.notify method.
If you rename notify in notifyPaypal, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the raply, Do you know how i can modify the plugin?

Comment: There is a groovy Class called PaypalController. Change `def notify` in `def notifyPaypal`.
Also in PaypalUrlMappings, you would like to map this new action name as follow :
`"/paypal/notify/$buyerId/$transactionId"(controller:"paypal", action:"notifyPaypal")`