# Grails 2.0 and PayPal plugin

Tags: grails, paypal, spring-security

I've installed the newest Grails `PayPal-Plugin (0.6.4)` and got the following error:

```
Problems occurred (un)installing plugins. See details for more information
------System.out:-----------
| Loading Grails 2.0.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Compiling 97 source files
| Compiling 97 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\Users\username\.grails\2.0.0\projects\projectname\plugins\paypal-0.6.4\grails-app\controllers\org\grails\paypal\PaypalController.groovy: -1: The return type of java.lang.Object notify() in org.grails.paypal.PaypalController is incompatible with void notify() in java.lang.Object
. At [-1:-1]  @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
------System.err:-----------
```

I fixed it by renaming `notify()` into `notifyPaypal()` => [Error PayPal plugin on grails 2.0.0.RC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492661/error-paypal-plugin-on-grails-2-0-0-rc3)

But the plugin seems to disturb springSecurity because I got the following error if I try to login:

```
| Error 2012-02-05 21:42:07,245 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-8] ERROR [/projectname].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/projectname] threw exception
Message: The specified user domain class 'Person' is not a domain class
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that two versions have been released since 0.6.4, and it now behaves as you asked regarding the 'notify()' method (probably thanks to your report).

http://grails.org/plugin/paypal/

(just saying it here for any casual reader to know)